# On URL open different team members

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple team members on a team page, with specific ids for each profile.

```
<div id="team-amy-content" class="team-container team-slide-active">
<div class="team-slide"> 

    <div class="team-slide-container" id="">
        <div class="team-image">
        </div>

        <div class="team-text">
        </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the profile will trigger on click adding

```
.team-slide-active {
display: block;
}


jQuery('.team-amy').click(function() {
jQuery('#team-amy-content').toggleClass('team-slide-active');
});
```

This opens the accordion pop-up with an on-click add class function.
However, I'm looking to make this trigger on page-load.

Because we have multiple team members I only want that specific profile to open if they visit a dedicated URL for example /#team1   /#team2

Comment: Can you please be more specific and provide relevant code? It's hard to determine what's going wrong without more information/code.

Comment: Sure, I've added some more information/code to give you more of an understanding.

Comment: I feel like there's still some code missing because I tried making a code pen for it and nothing shows up. For one thing, when I use jQuery I never use `jQuery(selector)` I use the dollar sign. Something like `$(selector)`. As for the on page load I don't see you wrapping that function in an onload event listener. Something like `$(document).ready(function () { jQuery('#team-amy-content').toggleClass('team-slide-active'); });`

Comment: I've found a solution -    

      <?php $name = $_GET['name']; 
      if($name != ""){ ?>
 <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#team-<?php echo $name; ?>-content").addClass("team-slide- 
        active");
  });
 </script>
      <? } ?>

Comment: Cool. What was the issue?

Comment: Basically wanted an id to trigger on page load.  if you use a bespoke url like adding #teammmber1 on the end